# programming in matlab (how to process in real time)

Tags: matlab

i am trying to make a spectrogram in matlab, 
here is my code:

```
% Record your voice for 100 seconds.
recObj = audiorecorder;
disp('Start speaking.')
recordblocking(recObj, 100);

% Store data in double-precision array.
my= getaudiodata(recObj);
figure;
specgram(my,512);
```

problem is that while i am speaking i want the spectrogram to be shown, so it should be updating as i speak. How can i plot the spectrogram while the audio is coming from microphone? so i should be able to see spectrogram in real time

I also tried this

```
% Record your voice for 100 seconds.
recObj = audiorecorder;
disp('Start speaking.')
a=0;
figure;
while a<60
    recordblocking(recObj, 100);

    % Store data in double-precision array.
    my= getaudiodata(recObj);

    specgram(my,512);
    a=a+1;
end
```

but it will only display the spectrogram when the while loop fishes (so after running 60 times)

Comment: I am no expert in matlab but dont you just need a loop around lines 4 through 9? By the way, this is tagged as C, but i cannot see the relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possible implementation. The main problem was that you forget to call [DRAWNOW](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/drawnow.html) at the end of each loop:

```
Fs = 8000;                    %# sampling frequency in Hz
T = 1;                        %# length of one interval signal in sec
t = 0:1/Fs:T-1/Fs;            %# time vector
nfft = 2^nextpow2(Fs);        %# n-point DFT
numUniq = ceil((nfft+1)/2);   %# half point
f = (0:numUniq-1)'*Fs/nfft;   %'# frequency vector (one sided)

%# prepare plots
figure
hAx(1) = subplot(211);
hLine(1) = line('XData',t, 'YData',nan(size(t)), 'Color','b', 'Parent',hAx(1));
xlabel('Time (s)'), ylabel('Amplitude')
hAx(2) = subplot(212);
hLine(2) = line('XData',f, 'YData',nan(size(f)), 'Color','b', 'Parent',hAx(2));
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'), ylabel('Magnitude (dB)')
set(hAx, 'Box','on', 'XGrid','on', 'YGrid','on')
%#specgram(sig, nfft, Fs);

%# prepare audio recording
recObj = audiorecorder(Fs,8,1);

%# Record for 10 intervals of 1sec each
disp('Start speaking...')
for i=1:10
    recordblocking(recObj, T);

    %# get data and compute FFT
    sig = getaudiodata(recObj);
    fftMag = 20*log10( abs(fft(sig,nfft)) );

    %# update plots
    set(hLine(1), 'YData',sig)
    set(hLine(2), 'YData',fftMag(1:numUniq))
    title(hAx(1), num2str(i,'Interval = %d'))
    drawnow                   %# force MATLAB to flush any queued displays
end
disp('Done.')
```

[image: screenshot]

I simply display the frequency components in each iteration. You should be able to modify that to show the spectrogram if you want...

Answer (score 6):

MATLAB is intrinsically single-threaded.  Only one thing can happen at a time.  This makes real time tasks somewhat difficult.  As you noted, `recordblocking` does not return control to your script until those 100 seconds have elapsed.  The key is in the word *blocking*.

The way around this is with [callbacks and non-blocking functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f9-38012.html).  The audiorecorder object has a few methods and properties that enable this kind of behavior.

The [`audiorecorder` properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/audiorecorder.html):
- `StartFcn`: Set a function that will execute upon starting an asynchronous recording
- `StopFcn`: The function to be executed upon stopping a recording
- `TimerFcn`: The function to be executed every `TimerPeriod` seconds during a recording.

Then the [`record` method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/audiorecorder.record.html) will start the recording and process in the background, calling the above functions as directed.

By regularly updating your data in the callback function, you may update your plot.  Unfortunately, this is similarly not trivial to do in an efficient manner that allows for live updates.  But this should get you started.

Comment: @Rave: I'm not going to code this for you. This is a broad question, and deals with some rather fundamental techniques in MATLAB programming. Please read through the links above (particularly the [Program Scheduling Fundamental Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f9-38012.html)). If you have specific questions in the implementation I'm sure I or someone else here can answer it for you.  But StackOverflow is not a code generation site.

Comment: something like this.

audio_recorder = audiorecorder(Fs, n_bits, n_channels);
 set(audio_recorder, myfunctionAtrecord); ?
i understand how to create it (by reading the document), but i don't know how to call it

Comment: i did it here i posted it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682073/matlab-programming-error-recorder-is-empty:
since i can't post code in comment box. when i try to spectrogram, i get recorder is empty error.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing to do is place your code in a loop to keep updating the figure.  But be aware that Matlab is not really designed for this sort of task, so I don't know how much success you'll have.  Have you tried Googling for free software which does this for you?  I'd be surprised if there was nothing out there which didn't do this already.

Comment: sorry, for past 3 days->i worked on C and haven't slept much.
finally decided to switch over to matlab, since i can convert it into an .exe

Sorry about it, edited.