# Why is the Recorder empty when running this MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab

So I wrote this, basically to update the spectrogram in real time.

```
function spec(Fs, n_bits, n_channels, update_rate)
%# Initialise default parameters if not supplied
if (~exist('Fs', 'var'))
    Fs          = 44000;
end
if (~exist('n_bits', 'var'))
    n_bits      = 16;
end
if (~exist('n_channels', 'var'))
    n_channels  = 2;
end
if (~exist('update_rate', 'var'))
    update_rate = 5;
end
plot_colors = hsv(n_channels);

%# Initialise plots, one above each other in a single figure window
figure;

%# Time Domain plot
hold on

%# Setup the audiorecorder which will acquire data off default soundcard
audio_recorder = audiorecorder(Fs, n_bits, n_channels);

set(audio_recorder, 'TimerFcn', {@audioRecorderTimerCallback, ...
                                  audio_recorder});
set(audio_recorder, 'TimerPeriod', 1/update_rate);
set(audio_recorder, 'BufferLength', 1/update_rate);

%# Start the recorder
record(audio_recorder);

end

function audioRecorderTimerCallback(obj, event, audio_recorder)

Fs           = get(obj, 'SampleRate');
num_channels = get(obj, 'NumberOfChannels');
num_bits     = get(obj, 'BitsPerSample');

try
    if (num_bits == 8)
        data_format = 'int8';
    elseif (num_bits == 16)
        data_format = 'int16';
    elseif (num_bits == 32)
        data_format = 'double';
    else
        error('Unsupported sample size of %d bits', num_bits);
    end

    %# stop the recorder, grab the data, restart the recorder. May miss some data
    stop(obj);
    data = getaudiodata(obj, data_format);

    record(obj);

    if (size(data, 2) ~= num_channels)
        error('Soundcard does not support acquisition of %d channels', ...
              length(num_channels))
    end
    data_fft    = fft(double(data));        
    specgram(data_fft,512);                
catch
    %# Stop the recorder and exit
    stop(obj)
    rethrow(lasterror)
end    
drawnow;
end
```

I always end up with an empty recorder.

I don't understand why there is this problem, I did record first.

Comment: This code is very helpful for me. One useful modification: don't stop and start the recorder in the callback. I mean remove `stop(obj)` and `record(obj)` and simply read the data, noting that the data length will continuously increase. This will prevent the occasions when we miss some data.

Comment: Noting that the `stop` command stops recording to the buffer and the `record` command uses a new buffer, the buffer will continue to grow with the modification I gave above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `spec` function doesn't return anything, so the audio that you've recorded is discarded when the function exits.

Change the function signature to

```
function audio_recorder = spec(Fs, n_bits, n_channels, update_rate)
```

---

One minor style point is that you can set default values for functions much more cleanly with (cue shameless self-promotion) [SetDefaultValue](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27056-set-default-values).

Comment: @@@@ thanks soooo much, the setting default values, i learned that from an example on the internet, thanks for the easier way :) also do you know how to increase the quality of the spctrogram display, i mean when its plot, it looks almost like pixels

Answer (score 0):

Another trick would be to add this at the end of your SPEC function:

```
uiwait
set(audio_recorder, 'StopFcn','uiresume');
```