# Real-time measuring fundamental frequency of voice signal using matlab

Tags: matlab, real-time, signal-processing

I want to display the fundamental frequency of a voice signal while recording using matlab. I found here [programming in matlab (how to process in real time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681063/programming-in-matlab-how-to-process-in-real-time) how to do the real-time part.

I learned that one of the techniques that are used to determine the fundamental frequency of a signal is the autocorrelation method. Also found a piece of code which implemented it.

Now I added the piece of code into the one found in the link above, but since I am a newbie in this field, I am not sure if what I've done does what I want - does the last plot display the fundamental frequency for each of the pieces of signal of length=1 second?

```
clear all
clc

Fs = 8000;                    %# sampling frequency in Hz
T = 1;                        %# length of one interval signal in sec
t = 0:1/Fs:T-1/Fs;            %# time vector
nfft = 2^nextpow2(Fs);        %# n-point DFT
numUniq = ceil((nfft+1)/2);   %# half point
f = (0:numUniq-1)'*Fs/nfft;   %'# frequency vector (one sided)

%# prepare plots
figure
hAx(1) = subplot(311);
hLine(1) = line('XData',t, 'YData',nan(size(t)), 'Color','b', 'Parent',hAx(1));
xlabel('Time (s)'), ylabel('Amplitude')
hAx(2) = subplot(312);
hLine(2) = line('XData',f, 'YData',nan(size(f)), 'Color','b', 'Parent',hAx(2));
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'), ylabel('Magnitude (dB)')
set(hAx, 'Box','on', 'XGrid','on', 'YGrid','on')
%#specgram(sig, nfft, Fs);

%# prepare audio recording
recObj = audiorecorder(Fs,8,1);

%# Record for 10 intervals of 1sec each
disp('Start speaking...')
for i=1:10
    recordblocking(recObj, T);

    %# get data and compute FFT
    sig = getaudiodata(recObj);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    ms20=Fs/50; % minimum speech Fx at 50Hz 
    r=xcorr(sig,'coeff'); 
    %d=(-ms20:ms20)/Fs; % times of delays 
    subplot(3,1,3); 
    plot(r); 
    legend('Autocorrelation'); 
    xlabel('Delay (s)'); 
    ylabel('Correlation coeff.'); 

    %55555555555555555555555555555555555   
%     R = xcorr (x);
     r = r(160:end);
%     n = 0:159; plot (n, R);

    % some constants
    Lmin = 20; Lmax = 146;
    thr = 0.3; % maximum needs to be at least thr * R[0]
    % detect lag
    [Rmax,ii] = max(r((Lmin+1):(Lmax+1))); % needs to add 1 because of Matlab indexing
    if Rmax >= thr * r(1) % R[0] in Matlab indexing
    L=ii+Lmin-1; % and here needs to remove it again...
    else
    L=0;
    end
    %hold on; plot (L,Rmax,'or'); hold off;

    % show lag in samples
    L
    % in seconds
    T0 = L / 8000
    % and fundamental frequency in Hz
    F0 = 1/T0


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    fftMag = 20*log10( abs(fft(sig,nfft)) );

    %# update plots
    set(hLine(1), 'YData',sig)
    set(hLine(2), 'YData',fftMag(1:numUniq))
    title(hAx(1), num2str(i,'Interval = %d'))
    drawnow                   %# force MATLAB to flush any queued displays
end
disp('Done.')
```

According to http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/~grezl/ZRE/comp_labs/03_pitch_codec_en.pdf, I added a few lines to my code(between `%5555555`). The promblem is it outputs the same fundamental frequency. Why is that happening and how could I solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not really clear what part of code you are unsure about. Please be more specific.

Comment: I'm not sure if the result (last plot) displays the fundamental frequency for the signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows the autocorrelation, not the fundamental frequency, updated every 1 second. Code execution waits at `recordblocking` until recording is done, then everything is plotted and then you record again, so total time of that loop will be a little bit more than 10 seconds.

If you have a clear note, with one frequency only, you'd get a nice sine wave of that frequency in your autocorrelation. If someone is speaking, that would be a pretty messy plot. Subplot 2 will show you your frequency content, which could give an indication of clear base frequencies.

Try this approach first with inputting clean sine waves to see how to interpret your plots. Then maybe try a note from an instrument (will include a lot of other frequencies) or try holding a note singing (good luck) and then think about whether this approach holds for speaking.

Honestly, a base frequency of someone speaking is not going to be easy. Also because of all the pauses between words, different tones in different words, etc. You could btw low pass filter to get some of the high frequency mess out.

Comment: Ok, I added some code to it, according to the link, but I don't know why the output is the same for each signal sequence.

Comment: Have you defined `x` somewhere? I'd suggest to put `clear all` at the beginning of your code to make sure you're not using old variables in your workspace.

Comment: Also, you're variable `R` is not used. The extraction of the most prominent frequency is likely done by finding the index where `max(R(..` occurs. I would also say that your fundamental frequency is not necessarily the largest component? - but the lowest nonzero frequency component. (also add 'x = sig', see previous comment)

Comment: Edited my code. I did not know that old variables from workspace could be used. I checked again the last linked Replaced all `R` and `x` occurences with `r`. Looks ok now. Also, you are right about the fundamental frequency being the lowest component a the waveform. But I extract the maximum from the autocorrelated waveform. Should I still choose the minimum?

Comment: `x` is your signal, `r` is your autocorrelation, so don't change `x` into `r`. Anyway, [here](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/~grezl/ZRE/lectures/05_pitch_en.pdf) are some lecture notes of the same class you linked to. They seem to imply that the point of _largest_ autocorrelation is linked to the fundamental frequency. I would think that it isn't as straight forward as that. I'm probably wrong. (edit: don't use the minimum of `r`)

Comment: I changed `x` into `r` because it should've been `r` from the beginnig. I misplaced it the first time. The original lines had r, not the signal `x`: `[Rmax,ii] = max(R((Lmin+1):(Lmax+1)));` `if Rmax >= thr * R(1)`. Thank you for your help.